# How to make Control work for Forms?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I made a reuseable control for our little team in WPF: a simple Dialog, that we use often.
The handling of the window is done in a private method:

```
private static void ExecuteInternal(
        Window owner,
        string windowTitle,
        string label,
        object operation,
        MyDialogSettings settings)
    {
        MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(windowTitle, settings);
        dialog.Owner = owner;
        dialog.Label = label;

        ShowDialog();
    }
```

The public call has a `System.Windows.Window` as parameter (--> WPF Window) and my function sets the `Owner` to this window.
Now my colleage wants to use this Window from a Windows Forms application.

My first thought was to overload the public function call with a form and then handle it with the `WindowInteropHelper` internally (see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhendersblog/archive/2005/10/04/476921.aspx)

But I then would have to reference `Windows.Forms` in every (WPF)-Project that uses my library.
Because I cannot access the window instance from outside the WindowInteropHelper-thing cannot done in the Forms application.

Any ideas?

Comment: Keep wpf library. Rest is a problem of your colleague: he wants it in winforms, he does `WindowInteropHelper` magic himself.

Comment: But then he would need a reference to my WPF Window (`MyDialog`). And that is inaccessable because it is in the private method. So he can not use the `WindowInteropHelper`

Comment: Why is that? Just give him window instance. What is the problem with that? Make it very secure (via public method which required password lol) if it's a big secret for wpf-colleagues.

Comment: Hmmm... it's not that easy... It is a dialog that pops up when calling a static function and closes itself after operation done (like a progress-dialog). So there is no chance to get the instance of window (not before calling `Execute`)

Comment: You can report progress somehow and make your nice looking wpf window optional. Then winforms-guy can draw his own ugly winforms progress dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see with this approach is that the reusable control is not reusable at all. As you note, the main method uses WPF-only types that cannot be used anywhere else, so reusage on WinForms is not possible as it stands now.

To be able to do so you would need to extract the main logic and visuals of the dialog window into an user control (so it can be hosted in  WinForms). This is the first thing I would do:

```
<UserControl .......>
    <Grid>
        <!-- Other controls you have on the dialog -->
        <Button Content="Accept"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Pretty easy, just move all the content to an user control. Then the window itself becomes trivial by just including this control:

```
<Window .......>
    <controls:MyDialogContent ..../>
</Window>
```

So far nothing changes, and the method you posted is works exactly the same as before. We'll leave it as being WPF-only and in turn implement an almost-equal method for WinForms.

On the WinForms project, now you have to create the form that will take the place of `MyDialog`. This form can be as simple as the WPF version, just an [ElementHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx) that will contain the UserControl that you separated previously, with maybe any properties/methods needed for your logic.

The last part is to provide a WinForms method to call it, akin to the WPF one. This could be as simple as something like this:

```
private static void ExecuteInternal(Form owner,
                                    string windowTitle,
                                    string label,
                                    object operation,
                                    MyDialogSettings settings)
{
    MyDialogForm dialog = new MyDialogForm(windowTitle, settings);
    dialog.Owner = owner;
    dialog.Label = label;

    dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my real problem... to open a WPF-window from a Form isn't a problem. So you don't need to wrap the things in a UserControl. With your last `ExecuteInternal` version you publish a Form to the interface and so everyone that uses the library has to reference Forms-namespace (even only-WPF-users). That's what I wanted to avoid

Comment: That version of the `ExecuteInternal` (as well as your own) is not meant to be reusable, as you note, it's tied to WPF/WinForms.  The only thing that can be exported as part of a public library is the `UserControl` itself, not the `Window`, not the `ExecuteInternal` parts. Those are tied to their respective technologies, but the usercontrol is interoperable in both environments. Consider `ExecuteInternal` a helper method only, the only part that must be copy-pasted into each other project as boiler-plate, hence you'll end up with two of them, being `private` methods only.